# Explode dataset based on a specific column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to explode my dataset based on a specific column in Python.

**Data**

```
id  type    date    stat    energy
aa  ss      Q1 2022 3       10
aa  ss      Q2 2022 2       10
bb  uu      Q1 2022 1       15
bb  uu      Q2 2022 3       15
cc  ii      Q1 2022 0       0
```

**Desired**

```
id  type    date    stat    energy
aa  ss     Q1 2022  3       10
aa  ss     Q1 2022  3       10
aa  ss     Q1 2022  3       10
aa  ss     Q2 2022  2       10
aa  ss     Q2 2022  2       10
bb  uu     Q1 2022  1       15
bb  uu     Q2 2022  3       15
bb  uu     Q2 2022  3       15
bb  uu     Q2 2022  3       15
cc  ii     Q1 2022  0       0
```

**Doing**

```
df.explode(list['stat'])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.index.repeat`:

```
repeats = np.where(df['stat'] == 0, 1, df['stat'])
# OR
repeats = df['stat'].clip(lower=1)

out = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(repeats)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)

# Output
   id type     date  stat  energy
0  aa   ss  Q1 2022     3      10
1  aa   ss  Q1 2022     3      10
2  aa   ss  Q1 2022     3      10
3  aa   ss  Q2 2022     2      10
4  aa   ss  Q2 2022     2      10
5  bb   uu  Q1 2022     1      15
6  bb   uu  Q2 2022     3      15
7  bb   uu  Q2 2022     3      15
8  bb   uu  Q2 2022     3      15
9  cc   ii  Q1 2022     0       0
```

Comment: sure - thank you the original soln works- was wondering what the edit changes? @corralien

Comment: Because if you repeat a row zero time, the row disappears so I need to keep at least one instance (your row 'cc')

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be

```
df['stat'] = [[x]*x if x > 0 else [x] for x in df['stat']]
new = df.explode('stat')
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster and neater way to do it is to use `np.repeat`

```
m=df['stat'].ge(1)#Isolate rows to be duplicated
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df[m].values,df.loc[m,'stat'], axis=0)#convert to numpy array and duplicate conditionally
                    , columns=df.columns)#Convert back to df
       .append(df[~m])#Reappend rows that had had zero dup required
      )
print(df1)
```